# How use a ScrollTo function in ScrollView in function component?

Tags: react-native

I need to set the ScrollView element to the position I need (5 slide, fo example), when element did mount. How can I do it in function component? In react-native

Answer (score 2):

Use Ref and onContentSizeChange

```
const ref = React.useRef(null);

<ScrollView
    ref={ref}
    onContentSizeChange={() => {ref.current.scrollTo({x:1000,animated: false, duration:0})}}
  >
```